# Unexpected NullReferenceException in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a Razor view that starts like:

```
@using My.Models
@model MySpecificModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Title";  
    // NullReferenceException here:
    string dateUtc =  
        (Model == null ? DateTime.UtcNow.ToShortDateString() :
                         Model.Date.ToShortDateString());
```

I see no reason for the NullReferenceException in the last line (note: the " = ? :" stuff is on one line in my source code.  It is formatted to fit here.)

I then remove the declaration of/assignment to `dateUtc` and the NullReferenceException moves up to the ViewBag.Title line:

```
@using My.Models
@model MySpecificModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Title";  // NullReferenceException here:
```

How can this possibly happen?  `ViewBag` is of course not null.

**NOTE 1**: This only happens if `Model` is null.

**NOTE 2**: MySpecificModel.Date is of type DateTime, so can never be null.

Comment: It seems that razor doesn't really point the error accurately and it's possbile that the exception occurs later in the view. If it's not that, then just use the Null object pattern for the model.

Comment: @MikeSW: What is "the Null object pattern"?

Comment: You provide an empty default model which does nothing. It will be just so the Model isn't null. It will help to have an IsEmpty property . Better yet, if it can be applied in your case, a model with default values. The important thing is the Model not being null ever.

Comment: @MikeSW: That's exactly what I ended up doing.  Feel free to add as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You provide an empty default model which does nothing. It will be just so the Model isn't null. It will help to have an IsEmpty property . Better yet, if it can be applied in your case, a model with default values. The important thing is the Model not being null ever

Answer (score 4):

A NullReferenceException on ViewBag.Title can indicate the error is really on a nearby line. In this example the error was thrown on line 1 but the real error was the null Model.Invoice in line 3.

```
<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<div class="pull-right">
    <button onclick="addInvoice('@Model.Invoice.InvoiceId');">Add Invoice</button>
</div>
```

Also ASP.NET MVC Razor does not handle nulls in ternary statements like C# does.

```
//Ternaries can error in Razor if Model is null
string date = (Model == null ? DateTime.Now : Model.Date);

//Change to
string date = null;
if (Model == null)
    date = DateTime.Now;
else
    date = Model.Date;
```

Comment: Same here.. ViewBag error was on line 6 ( @ViewBag.Title ).   But the actual erroe was on line 2 ( ViewData["PageHeader"] )   Once I set the view data from the controller, the null reference exception was gone.

Answer (score 3):

You will get a null exception if you do not pass any model to the view and still have the view bound to a model e.g.:

```
@model MySpecificModel
```

When you did not pass such a model to the view from your controller.

Comment: That's a good thought, but I do pass *null* to the view as the model parameter.

Comment: Try removing `ViewBag.Title = "My Title";  ` as well and see what happens :)